# Required function within an if statement in Helm3

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'd like to know how can I declare a particular values entry as **[required](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#know-your-template-functions)** within an **if statement** using **helm 3**.

**template.yaml**

```
{{ required "Value of [varTest] variable is required" .Values.varTest }}

{{- if ne (.Values.varTest | lower | quote) "some_value" }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: event-chronjob
  namespace: tests-ns
spec:
  schedule: "*/2 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: event
              image:  some-image:latest
{{- end }}
```

**values.yaml**

```
varTest: ""
```

When I execute the **helm install --set varTest="some_value"** command I get the following error:

> Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: YAML parse error on
> ../templates/template.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line
> 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Comment: What's the context this is running in?  Is this at the top level of a `templates/*.yaml` file, or in a `define` function; if the latter, how is it being called?  Which line is line 4?

Comment: (Separately from that error, the conditional will always fail; once you `quote` the string, you should get out a value like `"\"some_value\""`.)